# set $GOPATH for a vscode project / terminals

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I want to set $GOPATH for each vscode project/workspace. Right now, in .vscode/settings.json, I have:

```
{
    "go.gopath": "$HOME/codes/huru"
}
```

I close vscode and reopened, and at the command line terminal, I echo $GOPATH, and it's empty. I was hoping that vscode would read the env variable from "go.gopath", but it seems not have to done so.

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: why would you want that, `$GOPATH` defaults to `$HOME/go`, `go env GOPATH` would revel that, If you want `$GOPATH` to be visible from shell, then set it in your user profile or shell profile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `go.gopath` on *user settings* or *workspace settings* will replace the GOPATH value on the VSCode. This particular GOPATH value is the one that shows up whenever `Go: Current GOPATH` command is executed on VSCode, so it is **not the `$GOPATH` environment variable**.

Explanation from [GOPATH in the VS Code Go extension](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/gopath.md):

> By default, the extension uses the value of the environment variable GOPATH. If no such environment variable is set, the extension runs go env and uses the GOPATH reported by the go command.
>
> Note that, much like a `PATH` variable, GOPATH can contain multiple directory paths, separated by `:` or `;`. This allows you to set different GOPATHs for different projects.
>
> Setting `go.gopath` in your user settings overrides the environment's GOPATH value.
>
> Workspace settings override user settings, so you can use the go.gopath setting to set different GOPATHs for different projects. A GOPATH can also contain multiple directories, so this setting is not necessary to achieve this behavior.

Below is an example I've made up that might be useful on trying to understand the differences.

- For example, I already set the `$GOPATH` env on my local with a certain value. Then I set the `go.gopath` on the *user settings* (with different value compared to the `$GOPATH`). When I execute the command `Go: Current GOPATH`, a popup on the bottom right appears, showing the very same value as on my `go.gopath` settings. I put **red line** on all of this.
- But, whenever I execute shell command `echo $GOPATH` on the terminal, the output is still the `$GOPATH` value from my env variable **(blue line)**. This is because `go.gopath` setting will not replace the `$GOPATH` env variable.

[image]

---

In your case, the `echo $GOPATH` return empty output because you haven't set the `$GOPATH` environment variable.